# how build the webpack.config.prod.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I use React.js, Windows in my webpage project and want to apply the settings of webpack.config.prod.js to the project.
So I used command below at Webstorm terminal.

```
set NODE_ENV=production
.\node_modules\.bin\webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js
yarn build
serve -p 3000 -s build
```

This below is part of package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_PATH=src node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_PATH=src node scripts/start.js"
  },
```

Is it correct command to apply the webpack.config.prod.js to my create-react-app? I don't know how to check that the configuration of webpack.config.prod.js has been applied.

I also wonder if I need webpack-dev-server to apply webpack.config.prod.js.
Any help will be thankful. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

```
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
```

instead of this
use

```
NODE_ENV=production .\node_modules\.bin\webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js
```

It will build with production config
Now run yarn run build

Comment: Thanks for Answer! Setting the script like : `"build": "NODE_ENV=production .\node_modules\.bin\webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js"` , and type `yarn build`. Do I understand well?